# sqlite selectObject method , %%%@%% stuff

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uisearchbar

So I'm writing a search function for my app and the code is like this:

```
- (void) selectObject: (NSString *)notes{
    [axKnotes removeAllObjects];
    [notesName removeAllObjects];
    NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT NOTESNAME, NOTESCONTENT, STATUS FROM axKnotes WHERE NOTESCONTENT LIKE '%%%@%%'", notes];
    //there's a problem NSLog(sql);
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *ch0=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:ch0];
            [notesName addObject:name];
            //content
            char *ch1= (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:ch1];
            [axKnotes addObject:content];
        }
    }
}

- (void) searchBar: (UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    [self selectObject:searchText];
    [self.tableOfNotes reloadData];
}
```

The %%%@%% works perfectly in another app but here as I type(text changes), the array is cleared immediately and never changes again. And the NSLog says like:
[image]
when I typed the string "note1", and last night it didn't recognize my strings at all, and nslogged all kinds of garbled things like $#$*#%#**(you know.)
I'm hoping someone can help me out real quick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `%%%@%%` is correct (with a caveat I'll talk about later). When I ran your code, I saw:

```
2015-11-19 10:23:57.981 MyApp[78060:30221665] SELECT NOTESNAME, NOTESCONTENT, STATUS FROM axKnotes WHERE NOTESCONTENT LIKE '%N%'
2015-11-19 10:23:58.867 MyApp[78060:30221665] SELECT NOTESNAME, NOTESCONTENT, STATUS FROM axKnotes WHERE NOTESCONTENT LIKE '%No%'
2015-11-19 10:23:59.576 MyApp[78060:30221665] SELECT NOTESNAME, NOTESCONTENT, STATUS FROM axKnotes WHERE NOTESCONTENT LIKE '%Not%'
2015-11-19 10:24:00.160 MyApp[78060:30221665] SELECT NOTESNAME, NOTESCONTENT, STATUS FROM axKnotes WHERE NOTESCONTENT LIKE '%Note%'
2015-11-19 10:24:00.970 MyApp[78060:30221665] SELECT NOTESNAME, NOTESCONTENT, STATUS FROM axKnotes WHERE NOTESCONTENT LIKE '%Notes%'
2015-11-19 10:24:04.885 MyApp[78060:30221665] SELECT NOTESNAME, NOTESCONTENT, STATUS FROM axKnotes WHERE NOTESCONTENT LIKE '%Notes1%'
```

If you're really using this code and not seeing the `%` characters show up, there's got to be some fundamental disconnect. I'd suggest putting a breakpoint in there and make sure it's this method getting called and not some other permutation that might be lingering about. Also, make sure your code isn't using some non-ASCII `%` character.

If the problem is persisting, you might want to delete the app from the device/simulator and try again. If that doesn't do it, then find the derived data folder, quit Xcode, empty that derived data folder, and restart Xcode and try again.

However, if you fix this `%%%@%%` problem, and you're still not seeing your tables get refreshed, there are a diverse array of possible sources of that problem:

- `tableOfNotes` was `nil` (e.g. the outlet not hooked up properly);
- `axKnotes` and/or `notesName` was `nil` (e.g. the `NSMutableArray` was never properly instantiated); or
- the data source of the `UITableView` was not correctly hooked up.

If you have your SQLite code fixed and are still not seeing the table view update, you should examine these variables/properties (either with breakpoints or `NSLog`) and make sure none of them are `nil`.

--

A few unrelated caveats on this SQLite code:

1. I'd suggest logging `sqlite3_errmsg` if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed, Without that, errors will pass unobserved.
2. Remember to call `sqlite3_finalize` of the `sqlite3_stmt` reference. Without that, the code will leak.
3. You are using `initWithFormat` to build the SQL. That's a very bad idea because if the user ever searched for something like `O'Malley`, the SQL would fail. Instead, use a `?` placeholder in your SQL and remove the `'` characters from the SQL, and then bind values to that `?` placeholder:

   ```
   - (void) selectObject: (NSString *)notes{
       [axKnotes removeAllObjects];
       [notesName removeAllObjects];

       const char *sql = "SELECT NOTESNAME, NOTESCONTENT, STATUS FROM axKnotes WHERE NOTESCONTENT LIKE ?";
       NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", notes];

       sqlite3_stmt *statement;

       if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
           NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
           return;
       }

       if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
           NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
       }

       int rc;
       while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
           char *ch0=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
           NSString *name = ch0 ? [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:ch0] : @"";
           [notesName addObject:name];
           //content
           char *ch1= (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
           NSString *content = ch1 ? [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:ch1] : @"";
           [axKnotes addObject:content];
       }
       if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
           NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
       }

       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh. Wow! Thanks so much! Your answer just woke me up at 2:47 am here in China lol. I'll test it tomorrow, and this is the longest and nicest answer I've ever got, thanks!! Have a good day!